# How does PasswordEncoder get called in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm experimenting with spring boot (1.0.0, using boot web and security), and have a working web application whose secured endpoints are authenticated with a user like so. This code works (configure HttpSecurity omitted for brevity) requiring a username / password for http requests to certain endpoints:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Inject
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

In preparation for using spring security with users from a database, I put the security pieces together in a way that I think should work, but notably without any database at all. This is purely to experiment with the security related classes.

So the above code that used to configure that AuthenticationManagerBuilder changed to this:

```
// private test implementations so we can explore security without a database
// here all usernames and passwords are valid
// org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoder() {
        @Override public String encode(CharSequence cs) {
            return cs.toString();
        }
        @Override public boolean matches(CharSequence cs, String string) {
            return true;
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService createUserDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String string) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            return new User(); // a trivial implementation of UserDetails
        }
    };
}

@Bean
@Inject
public DaoAuthenticationProvider createDaoAuthenticationProvider(UserDetailsService service, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(service);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
    return provider;
}

@Bean
@Inject
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationProvider provider) throws Exception {
    // includes a trivial implementation of ObjectPostProcessor
    return new AuthenticationManagerBuilder(new NopPostProcessor())
            .authenticationProvider(provider)
            .build();
}
```

My custom user details service is called but my custom password encoder is never called, I verified this by setting breakpoints at the appropriate lines. And the authentication always fails.

How is the password encoder called? Shouldn't it be called with the authentication of every http request? Should I expect it to be called with the above configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ultimate answer is "download the spring security source and debug into it to find out what's going on."

I did that and immediately stumbled into an AccountStatusException... my simple UserDetails implementation had its enabled flag set to false by default, so the password was never verified after the user failed that check. Here are the actual answers to all my questions:

Q: How is the password encoder called?

A: step through the source in AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider

Q: Shouldn't it be called with the authentication of every http request?

A: No, it is called as needed (after user is retrieved and verified to be enabled)

Q: Should I expect it to be called with the above configuration?

A: The configuration is satisfactory as far as the wiring of the encoder and user service, but the configuration does not ensure it will be called.

Comment: If you have debug logging enabled, then you *should* see a message in the log saying that the user account is disabled and, in general, you should see the authentication failure logged with the exception type. So, while having the source available for debugging is always a good idea (and easy to set up with modern IDEs), the debug log provides a detailed account of what Spring Security is doing and should have been enough in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The `authenticate` method of AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider ( which is extended by DaoAuthenticationProvider)
is like this

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Assert.isInstanceOf(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class, authentication,
            messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.onlySupports",
                "Only UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is supported"));

        // Determine username
        String username = (authentication.getPrincipal() == null) ? "NONE_PROVIDED" : authentication.getName();

        boolean cacheWasUsed = true;
        UserDetails user = this.userCache.getUserFromCache(username);

        if (user == null) {
            cacheWasUsed = false;

            try {
                user = retrieveUser(username, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
            } catch (UsernameNotFoundException notFound) {
                logger.debug("User '" + username + "' not found");

                if (hideUserNotFoundExceptions) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                            "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
                } else {
                    throw notFound;
                }
            }

            Assert.notNull(user, "retrieveUser returned null - a violation of the interface contract");
        }

        try {
            preAuthenticationChecks.check(user);
            additionalAuthenticationChecks(user, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
        } catch (AuthenticationException exception) {
            if (cacheWasUsed) {
                // There was a problem, so try again after checking
                // we're using latest data (i.e. not from the cache)
                cacheWasUsed = false;
                user = retrieveUser(username, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
                preAuthenticationChecks.check(user);
                additionalAuthenticationChecks(user, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
            } else {
                throw exception;
            }
        }

        postAuthenticationChecks.check(user);

        if (!cacheWasUsed) {
            this.userCache.putUserInCache(user);
        }

        Object principalToReturn = user;

        if (forcePrincipalAsString) {
            principalToReturn = user.getUsername();
        }

        return createSuccessAuthentication(principalToReturn, authentication, user);
    }
```

As you can see after the user is loaded and confirmed present in repository, there is call to additionalAuthenticationChecks.If the user is not found then the additional check is not done. It is in the additionalcheck method that the password encoder is used. Here is the implementation in DaAuthenticationProvider

```
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Object salt = null;

        if (this.saltSource != null) {
            salt = this.saltSource.getSalt(userDetails);
        }

        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");

            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"), userDetails);
        }

        String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userDetails.getPassword(), presentedPassword, salt)) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");

            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"), userDetails);
        }
    }
```

As you can see this is where the password encoder is used to match the password presented with that stored in repository. So if the password encoder is not being called, one probable reason could be that the user was not found.

Comment: When you say "one reason could be that the user was not found" do you mean the user was not found in the repository? When I breakpoint in my custom UserDetailsService, I see the stack trace from AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate() to DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser() to my own loadUserByUsername(), as you described. However, the user is found (indeed a user *must* always be returned in my dummy implementation). Maybe my next step should be to attach the spring security sources and step through *that* in the debugger.

Comment: I don't think this was the correct answer to the question, but the gentle reminder to look at the spring security source did point me in the right direction. I'll at least upvote it.

Comment: That was what I was encouraging you to do :-) Spring security is a complex framework and many times I needed to debug through the source code to understand what is going on. Glad you found the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I'd change it to this:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { ... }

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() { ... }

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(this.userDetailsService());
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder());
    return provider;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return new AuthenticationManagerBuilder(new NopPostProcessor())
            .authenticationProvider(this.daoAuthenticationProvider())
            .build();
}
```

Anyway you should configure `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` with your custom `userDetailsService`:

```
auth.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService())
```

Comment: I tried this approach to ensure that the authentication provider was getting my custom password encoder (maybe spring created another one and it was getting injected in preference to mine or something). Unfortunately, this technique made no difference. (as an aside, I verified that the class of the encoder in daoAuthenticationProvder() is my custom one even when using @Inject)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue.
I realized that `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.obtainPassword`(request) was returning null. And that was failing the authentication later on.

My mistake was that I didn't have a 'password' field in my login form.
Solution: Add the id and name attribute in the password field of the form and set their value to the value of 'passwordParameter' value, which is 'password' by default.

So do check that basic issue first.
Hope it helps!